# How bittorrent tracker works?

Tags: bittorrent

I read official documetation [here](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) and wikipedia article about bittorrent client [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent) but couldn't find how tracker exactly work. As per my understanding tracker should know which peer have which piece of some file. For example client 1 have 5 pieces of file 1 and 10 pieces of file 2. In official documentation I see tracker have fields like `peer_id` `ip` `port` `uploaded` `downloaded` `left` and `event` but I don't see where is the information about which file we are tracking. For example if I ask tracker hey I need pieces for linux.torrent file, how tracker would answer me?

Comment: Unless you have a question about programming your own tracker or patching someone else's, this is not on-topic for SO and would be better suited to SuperUser.

Comment: I am trying to implement my own java based tracker, client etc. so I need information which fields I need in tracker and how client know which peers have pieces that it is interested for. I guess it should ask a tracker but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trackers job is, when a peer *announces* to a specific swarm (identified by the `info_hash`),to register that peer as active on that swarm and then send that peer a *peer list* with other peers active on that swarm.

A tracker does NOT keep track on which *pieces* or *files* a peer has.

I recommend you to read the inoffical protocol specification: https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification
it's bit easier do comprehend than the terse and dense BEP-3.

Comment: To make the answer even more helpful @Encombe, could you include what is a "swarm"? What is the exact difference between `keep track on which pieces or files a peer has.` (you said it doesn't) and a list of peers `active on that swarm and then send that peer a peer list with other peers active on that swarm.` ?

Comment: @encombe link is broken

Answer (score -2):

In official documentation there is bep for UDP tracker protocol [here](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html)